# Do ring laser gyros age with laser and dithering disabled?

Tags: nasa, attitude, deep-space, gyroscope

Laser fading seems to be a known issue with ring laser gyros. With their STEREO-B probe, NASA experienced a different, "unexpected" failure mode, giving false readings. The Honeywell MIMU's were well beyond the expected lifetime but still, there may be some lessons to be learned from this. Having a second IMU in hot standby increases redundancy in critical mission phases. During extended operations however, any spare unit that ages may better be sent into cold standby.

1. **Do ring laser gyros age (in deep space environment) with laser and dithering disabled?**
2. **Were laser and dither disabled on the spare unit for the STEREO mission?**
3. **Can the failure mode of STEREO-B's IMU's be attributed to the dithering mechanism?**

---

Some context to the question:

NASA's [STEREO](https://stereo.gsfc.nasa.gov/)-B is in uncontrolled spin (as of Oct 2016). Efforts to regain control [are ongoing](http://swrc.gsfc.nasa.gov/main//sites/swrc/presentations/2015_NASA_SWx_Workshop/Wilson_STEREO-LivingPastYourWarranty_20150923.pdf) following a [telemetry downlink in August 2016](http://www.theverge.com/2016/8/22/12589406/nasa-stereo-b-spacecraft-contact-deep-space-network) after two years of communication break. Control of the spacecraft [was lost](http://spaceref.com/solar-physics/loss-of-contact-with-stereo-behind.html) on Oct. 1 2014 due to an unlucky double failure during a planned reset sequence [in preparation](https://svs.gsfc.nasa.gov/11602) to solar conjunction (star tracker timeout + IMU fail).

The sequence of events is analyzed in this [presentation](http://swrc.gsfc.nasa.gov/main//sites/swrc/presentations/2015_NASA_SWx_Workshop/Wilson_STEREO-LivingPastYourWarranty_20150923.pdf), prepared by mission specialists at John Hopkins Lab.